# How to get random value from struct

Tags: swift, random, struct

How do I pick a random constant value from a struct?

```
struct randomMessage {
    static let message1 = "Message1"
    static let message2 = "Message2"
    static let message3 = "Message3"
    static let message4 = "Message4"
    static let message5 = "Message5"
}
```

Is the only way adding all the values to an array and picking the randomElement ?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @mag_zbc. I try add all value into array and pick it randomElement.

Comment: @KkMIW Thats a good approach.  So is a switch on a random int.  Show in your question what's wrong with that

Comment: But I don't want unnecessary created variable Array! Its struct can help me pick out the random elements from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep it packed in some type you better use `enum` instead:

```
enum RandomMessage: String, CaseIterable {
    case message1 = "Message1"
    case message2 = "Message2"
    case message3 = "Message3"
    case message4 = "Message4"
    case message5 = "Message5"

    static var get: String {
        return allCases.randomElement()!.rawValue
    }
}
```

This way you will guarantee that it will only have "fields" with messages, and if you get new messages you can just add new case and it will automatically be in `allCases` array.

To get random message do this:

```
let message = RandomMessage.get // one of the messages
```

Comment: this make sense! its only possible with enum! not struct class?

Comment: @KkMIW no, you don't get automatic access to all struct/class properties. Even for enums you only get this for free when the enum conforms to `CaseIterable`. You could try using reflection (`Mirror` type) to achieve the same for struct/class, but it's more work

Comment: CaseIterable!  Thanks David.  You deserver a upVote

Answer (score 2):

You can organize them in an array and from there select a random value as follows

```
let names = ["Zoey", "Chloe", "Amani", "Amaia"]
let randomName = names.randomElement()!
print(randomName)
```

Comment: I assume that what you need is to get a random message, from a series of predefined messages

Comment: This is what I did earlier !  I am looking is there alternative approach to do that?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?, so you can find an alternative

Comment: let randomeListMesage = [randomMessage.message1,randomMessage.message2,randomMessage.message3,randomMessage.message4,randomMessage.message5,randomMessage.message6,randomMessage.message7]
randomeListMessage.randomElement()!

Comment: The above code I tried before posting my question! which worked fine.  but I want to know do we construct struct which return random object from it?

Comment: If the objective is to obtain a random message from a series of predefined messages, I do not see the need to create a structure to obtain said message, it seems to me that an array is a solution for that problem, I emphasize if the objective is only to obtain a random message , from a series of predefined messages.  let randomeListMesage = [message1, message2, message3, message4]
let randommessage = randomeListMesage.randomElement()!

Comment: Thanks Daniel Fernando! that makes senses!

Comment: With pleasure friend :-)